# Append html table

Tags: javascript, dom, button, append, html-table

I need help. I want to append a table the same with the existing one the condition is example I've 2 rows when I click `na` + button on the first row beside `na` time the new append table should appear in between 1st and third row. 
Please help

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
    function clearNode(node){
        var child = node.childNodes[0];
        while(child != null)
        {
            node.removeChild(child);
            child = node.childNodes[0];
        }   
    }
    function addRow(table){
        var targetView = table;
        // CREATE ELEMENT   
        var newtr = document.createElement("tr");

        var newtd_c1 = document.createElement("td");
            newtd_c1.setAttribute("width","147");
            newtd_c1.setAttribute("align","center");
            newtd_c1.appendChild(
                input_data = document.createElement("input"),
                input_data.setAttribute("type","time"),
                input_data.setAttribute("size","10"),
                input_data.setAttribute("autofocus","true")
            );
        var newtd_c2 = document.createElement("td");
            newtd_c2.setAttribute("width","138");
            newtd_c2.setAttribute("align","center");
            newtd_c2.appendChild(
                selection = document.createElement("select"),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 1"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 1"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 2"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 2"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 3"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 3"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 4"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 4"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 5"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 5"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 6"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 6"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 7"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 7"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 8"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 8"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 9"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 9")))
            );
        var newtd_c3 = document.createElement("td");
            newtd_c3.setAttribute("width","98");
            newtd_c3.setAttribute("align","center");
            newtd_c3.appendChild(
                selection = document.createElement("select"),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 1"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 1"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 2"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 2"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 3"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 3"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 4"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 4"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 5"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 5"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 6"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 6"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 7"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 7"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 8"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 8"))),
                selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 9"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 9")))
            );
        var newtd_c4 = document.createElement("td");
            newtd_c4.setAttribute("width","119");
            newtd_c4.setAttribute("align","center");
            newtd_c4.appendChild(
                input_data = document.createElement("input"),
                input_data.setAttribute("type","text"),
                input_data.setAttribute("size","12"),
                input_data.setAttribute("placeholder","Value")
            );
        var newtd_c5 = document.createElement("td");
            newtd_c5.setAttribute("width","115");
            newtd_c5.setAttribute("align","center");
            newtd_c5.appendChild(
                input_data = document.createElement("input"),
                input_data.setAttribute("type","button"),
                input_data.setAttribute("value","Delete"),
                input_data.onclick = function(){ return clearNode(newtr); }
            );
        var newtd_c6 = document.createElement("td");
            newtd_c6.setAttribute("width","115");
            newtd_c6.setAttribute("align","center");
            newtd_c6.appendChild(
                input_data = document.createElement("input"),
                input_data.setAttribute("type","button"),
                input_data.setAttribute("value","+"),
                input_data.onclick = function(){ return addRow(table); }
            );

        newtr.appendChild(newtd_c1);
        newtr.appendChild(newtd_c2);
        newtr.appendChild(newtd_c3);
        newtr.appendChild(newtd_c4);
        newtr.appendChild(newtd_c5);
        newtr.appendChild(newtd_c6);

        targetView.appendChild(newtr);
    }
    function deleteRow(tableID){
        try{
            var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount=table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
                var row=table.rows[i];
                var chkbox=row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null!=chkbox&&true==chkbox.checked){
                    if(rowCount<=1){
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;i--;
                }
            }
        }catch(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    }


function addRowClone(nextrow){
    var targetView = document.getElementById("Data");
    // CREATE ELEMENT
    // COUNT LIST
    var list     = $(".datalisting").length;

    var newlist = list+1;
    alert(newlist);
    var newdiv   = document.createElement("div");
        newdiv.setAttribute("id","list_"+newlist);
        newdiv.setAttribute("class","datalisting");
        newdiv.setAttribute("style","margin:30px 0;");
    var newtable = document.createElement("table");
        newtable.setAttribute("class","dataTable");
        newtable.setAttribute("width","689");
        newtable.setAttribute("border","1");
        newtable.setAttribute("cellspacing","0");
        newtable.setAttribute("cellpadding","0");

    var newtr = document.createElement("tr");

    var newtd_c1 = document.createElement("td");
        newtd_c1.setAttribute("width","147");
        newtd_c1.setAttribute("align","center");
        newtd_c1.appendChild(
            input_data = document.createElement("input"),
            input_data.setAttribute("type","time"),
            input_data.setAttribute("size","10"),
            input_data.setAttribute("autofocus","true")
        );
        newtd_c1.appendChild(
            input_data = document.createElement("input"),
            input_data.setAttribute("type","button"),
            input_data.setAttribute("value","+"),
            input_data.onclick = function(){
                addRowClone("list_"+newlist);
            }
        );
    var newtd_c2 = document.createElement("td");
        newtd_c2.setAttribute("width","138");
        newtd_c2.setAttribute("align","center");
        newtd_c2.appendChild(
            selection = document.createElement("select"),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 1"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 1"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 2"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 2"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 3"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 3"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 4"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 4"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 5"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 5"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 6"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 6"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 7"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 7"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 8"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 8"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Value 9"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select 9")))
        );
    var newtd_c3 = document.createElement("td");
        newtd_c3.setAttribute("width","98");
        newtd_c3.setAttribute("align","center");
        newtd_c3.appendChild(
            selection = document.createElement("select"),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 1"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 1"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 2"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 2"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 3"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 3"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 4"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 4"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 5"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 5"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 6"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 6"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 7"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 7"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 8"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 8"))),
            selection.appendChild(option = document.createElement("option"),option.setAttribute("select","Source 9"),option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Source 9")))
        );
    var newtd_c4 = document.createElement("td");
        newtd_c4.setAttribute("width","119");
        newtd_c4.setAttribute("align","center");
        newtd_c4.appendChild(
            input_data = document.createElement("input"),
            input_data.setAttribute("type","text"),
            input_data.setAttribute("size","12"),
            input_data.setAttribute("placeholder","Value")
        );
    var newtd_c5 = document.createElement("td");
        newtd_c5.setAttribute("width","115");
        newtd_c5.setAttribute("align","center");
        newtd_c5.appendChild(
            input_data = document.createElement("input"),
            input_data.setAttribute("type","button"),
            input_data.setAttribute("value","Delete Main"),
            input_data.onclick = function(){ return clearNode(newdiv); }
        );
    var newtd_c6 = document.createElement("td");
        newtd_c6.setAttribute("width","115");
        newtd_c6.setAttribute("align","center");
        newtd_c6.appendChild(
            input_data = document.createElement("input"),
            input_data.setAttribute("type","button"),
            input_data.setAttribute("value","+"),
            input_data.onclick = function(){ return addRow(newtable); }
        );

    newtr.appendChild(newtd_c1);
    newtr.appendChild(newtd_c2);
    newtr.appendChild(newtd_c3);
    newtr.appendChild(newtd_c4);
    newtr.appendChild(newtd_c5);
    newtr.appendChild(newtd_c6);

    newtable.appendChild(newtr);
    newdiv.appendChild(newtable);

    if(nextrow != null){
        var prevlist = newlist-1;
        $(targetView).append($(newdiv)).insertAfter($(nextrow));
    }else{
        targetView.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
}
window.onload = function(){
    addRowClone();
}

</script>


</head>
<body>

    <div style="margin:10px 0;border:1px solid #000;width:629px;text-align:right;">
        <div style="padding-right:15px;">
            <input type="button" value="Add Observation" onClick="addRowClone();"/>
        </div>
    </div><div id="Data">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please compact your code to an illustrative minimal example (and use for loops. If you do the same thing ten times with only a number changing, that's a for loop right there). Also, please be more descriptive in what you actually need help with; just write full sentences so that everyone can understand what you're asking, ideally, with a jsfiddle.net example that shows where you got so far (again, reduced example, not a million table rows) so that we might modify that to show you how to get what you want, done.

Comment: And perhaps have a look into jQuery, it will sooth your javascript burdens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wont somethink like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/t3JkC/).
HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>First row</td>
        <!-- 'this' sends as argument to the addRow function - it's a button on which you click -->
        <td><button onclick="addRow(this);">Add row</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second row</td>
        <td><button onclick="addRow(this);">Add row</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And javascript:

```
function addRow(button) {
// get a table cell in which clicked button lies
var buttonTd = button.parentNode;
// get a table row in which clicked button lies 
var rowTr = buttonTd.parentNode;
// get a table tbody
var tableTbody = rowTr.parentNode;
// get a table
var tableTable = tableTbody.parentNode;

// clone table row in which clicked button lies
var newTr = rowTr.cloneNode(true);
// get a cell which holds name
var newTrNameTd = newTr.children[0];
// get a name, for first time it's 'First row' or 'Second row'
var oldName = newTrNameTd.innerHTML;
// adding to name ' new'
var newName = oldName + ' new';
// append name to the name's cell in cloned row
newTrNameTd.innerHTML = newName;

// try to get next row after that in which clicked button is lies 
var nextRow = rowTr.nextSibling;
// if we get this row
if (nextRow) {
    // append cloned row before it
    tableTbody.insertBefore(newTr, nextRow);
// if there was a last row
} else {
    // append cloned row in the end of the table
    tableTbody.appendChild(newTr);
}
}
```

Javascript have a function `cloneNode(true)` which clones the node you select.
`if` statement in code insert node after `nextRow`.
P.S. If you using `jQuery` use it in all code, or use simple javascript.

Comment: yes thats it... thank you so much... :)

Comment: @user2605454, no problem. If I answered your question just mark answer as approved.

Comment: Sir are you there? the function addRow there i cant figure out on what to do so that it will append on the next line not on the last line.... thanks

Comment: @user2605454 I give a cooments to code. If you a still can't understand how it works please tell me

Comment: sir... uhmmm im having problem on the addRow function...if im going to click na + button at the end how am i going to append it right next to the row..coz right now it will always append on the last row.. if it has 3 rows it appends on the 4th need help to append it right row

Comment: function addRow(table){
    var targetView = table;
    var newtr = document.createElement("tr");
    var newtd_c1 = document.createElement("td");
    newtd_c6.appendChild(
    input_data = document.createElement("input"),
    input_data.setAttribute("type","button"),
    input_data.setAttribute("value","+"),
    input_data.onclick = function(){ return addRow(table);});
    newtr.appendChild(newtd_c1);
    targetView.appendChild(newtr);}

Comment: see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/JXpfS/1/) link. Any questions?